# Adding a traditional legend to dumbbell plot in `ggalt::geom_dumbbell` in `R`

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, ggalt

How to add a traditional legend to dumbbell plot created using `ggalt::geom_dumbbell` in `R`?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011005/adding-a-legend-to-a-dumbbell-chart-in-r) has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40011216/3223138) with an in-chart legend. How to map the aesthetics to get a separate legend for the points on the side/bottom ?

```
library(ggalt)

df <- data.frame(trt=LETTERS[1:5], l=c(20, 40, 10, 30, 50), r=c(70, 50, 30, 60, 80))

ggplot(df, aes(y=trt, x=l, xend=r)) + 
  geom_dumbbell(size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Comment: @MrFlick the example is up.

Comment: So from the example, what do you want to be in the legend?

Comment: @MrFlick l = red and r = blue. They are two different columns in the data. I have tried individually plotting geom_point with scale_manual, but the mapping gets replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get a legend is to add a points layer based on the dataset in long format, mapping `color` to the grouping variable.

First, make a long format dataset via `gather` from *tidyr*.

```
df2 = tidyr::gather(df, group, value, -trt)
```

Then make the plot, adding the new points layer with the long dataset and using `scale_color_manual` to set colors.  I moved the `geom_dumbbell` specific aesthetics into that layer.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = trt)) + 
     geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = value, color = group), size = 3) +
     geom_dumbbell(aes(x = l, xend = r), size=3, color="#e3e2e1", 
                   colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                   dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
     theme_bw() +
     scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("red", "blue") )
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome - the only downside is that the ordering of my factors (y-axis) gets wiped out when I include the `geom_point` layer. Any idea how to add the legend and also maintain the custom-ordered factors?

Comment: @ForceLeft415 Hmm, I'm not sure.  Make sure your `trt` equivalent is in the same custom order in each dataset.  I thought it might be that the "long" dataset didn't maintain the factor order, but it looks like the current version of `gather()` maintains the level order from the original dataset.

Comment: and will this work on matplotlib? looks tricky plus @ForceLeft415 made a good point, there must be a better way

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed This answer is specific to **ggplot2**.  I have no idea how/if it would extend to matplotlib.  Generally speaking, since the OP example doesn't have an issue with factor order, setting the factor order of the dataset and then plotting is a fairly common approach for controlling ggplot2 axis order.  Other options include setting the `limits` and/or `breaks` in the appropriate `scale_*()` function.